# Only SSR / disable client side rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
<template>
  <nav v-once>
    <catalog-menu-container v-once :items="this.awd.children_data" />
  </nav>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';
import catalogMenuContainer from '~/components/catalog/menu/container.vue'

export default {
  name: 'catalog-menu',
  components: {
    catalogMenuContainer
  },
  async serverPrefetch () {
      let { data } = await axios.get('url')
      this.awd = data;
  }
}
</script>
```

The component in this code is rendered server side. But also, it gets rendered on client side once again. How to disable the client side rendering? I just want the html which has been generated on server side.
"v-once" doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration

Answer (score 1):

The vue docs are pretty clear on handling this with this [warning:](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#data-store)

> WARNING You should check if the component was server-side rendered in
>   the mounted hook to avoid executing the logic twice.

So you would want to add to your code:

```
mounted () {
    // If we didn't already do it on the server
    // we fetch the item
    if (!this.awd) {
      let { data } = await axios.get('url')
      this.awd = data;
    }
  },
```

Alternatively, and perhaps ideally, as you are using nuxt you could use [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) instead of `serverPrefetch`

```
async asyncData (context) {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`url`)
    return { context.awd: data }
  }
```